# Looping a .mouseup with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

Kind of feels like I am spamming questions by now, but w/e, I was just wondering if there is any way to loop a `.mouseup` function?

In my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var antal = document.getElementsByClassName("e");
    for (var i = 1; i <= antal.length; i++) {
        $("#e" + i).draggable({ 
            containment: '#glassbox', 
            scroll: false
        });
    }
    .mouseup(function(){ 
        var coords = [];
        var coord = $(this).position();
        var item = {
            coordTop: coord.left,
            coordLeft: coord.top
        };
        coords.push(item);
        var order = { coords: coords, id: 1 };
        $.post('updatecoords.php', 'data='+$.toJSON(order), function(response){
            if(response == "success") {
                $("#respond")
                   .html('<div class="success">X and Y Coordinates Saved!</div>')
                   .hide()
                   .fadeIn(1000);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#respond').fadeOut(1000);
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

the first part works without a problem and just the way I want it, all the looped divs are draggable and I can move them inside the glassbox div which is exactly what I want. The .mouseup function however, does not work and makes the boxes undraggable, and I was just wondering if there is a way I could do it like this or if I should just give up.

EDIT:

This is the PHP/HTML code I am using on the site which is connected to the javascript:

```
$antal = $mysqli->query("SELECT `Grupp ID` FROM `Elevgrupper` WHERE `Grupp ID`=25");
$num = $antal->num_rows;

$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT `Namn`, `Efternamn` FROM `Elever` WHERE `ID` IN (SELECT `Användar ID` FROM `Elevgrupper` WHERE `Grupp ID` = 25)");

for ($i = 1; $i<=$num; $i++){
    $get_coords = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM coords WHERE id = '" . $i . "'");
    $row = $get_coords->fetch_assoc();
    $ok = $res->data_seek($i-1);
    $row1 = $res->fetch_assoc();

    //
    $x = $row['x_pos'];
    $y = $row['y_pos']; 
    echo '<div id="e'. $i .'" class="e" style="left:'.$x.'px; top:'.$y.'px;"><p class="p'. $i .'" id="p' . $i .'">'. $row1["Namn"] . " " . $row1["Efternamn"] . '</p></div>';
    }
```

Edit #2:

This is a working version of the program without the use of a loop:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#e1").draggable({ 
            containment: '#glassbox', 
            scroll: false
     })     



    .mousemove(function(){
                    var coord = $(this).position();
                    $("p:last").text( "left: " + coord.left + ", top: " + coord.top );
     })

    .mouseup(function(){ 
            var coords=[];
            var coord = $(this).position();
            var item={ coordTop:  coord.left, coordLeft: coord.top  };
            coords.push(item);
            var order = { coords: coords, id: 1 };
            $.post('updatecoords.php', 'data='+$.toJSON(order), function(response){
                    if(response == "success") {
                        $("#respond").html('<div class="success">X and Y Coordinates Saved!</div>').hide().fadeIn(1000);
                        setTimeout(function(){ $('#respond').fadeOut(1000); }, 2000);
                    }
            });

    });
```

Edit #3:
Just remembered that this might also be vital information:

type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js">

type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js">

type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.json-2.2.min.js">

These are the links I use.

Comment: @Ivan edited the post

Comment: Something's definitely not right with your code. `.mouseup(function(){ ` should be preceded by a variable name, or a function call, or something.

Comment: @MátéSafranka I added a working version of the code without using a loop if you want to compare the loop to something that works hehe

Comment: Okay, so basically you want to add an event listener to all elements with class name `e`? Have you tried `$('.e').draggable(...).mouseup(...).mousemove(...)` ?

Comment: @MátéSafranka yeah exactly, I want to make it so that if I press an object it runs the save code and saves its' own coordinates, but with the .mouseup it says "unexpected token ." if I remove it, it says "mouseup is not defined"

Comment: Try `$('.e').draggable(...).on('mousemove', function() { ... }).on('mouseup', function() { ... });`